# How to get relations by model_type in target model Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a list of different messages (sms, phone calls, common messages, etc.) and I'm trying to connect this list in general table by `model_type` and `model_id`:

```
Schema::create('lead_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('lead_id')->nullable()->constrained('leads')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('model_type');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
    $table->index(['model_id', 'model_type'], 'lead_messages_model_id_model_type_index');
    $table->primary(['lead_id', 'model_id', 'model_type'], 'lead_messages_lead_model_type_primary');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then I can get feed for user.

Now I'm trying to get all entities by models. **Is it possible to get them by table field?**
Something like that (this is wrong code of course):

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->hasOne('model_type', 'id', 'model_id');
}
```

Comment: Assuming you've got a Message model, and that model needs to be associated to one of a different number of other models (PhoneCall, SMS, WhatsApp, etc.) then it sounds like you want to go down the Polymorphic relationship route. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it's easier than seems. There is an answer on my question [in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#morph-one-to-one-key-conventions). This code will give necessary data for me:

Model:

```
public function data()
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'model_type', 'model_id');
}
```

Service:

```
$response = LeadMessage::whereLeadId($request->lead_id)
    ->with('data')
    ->paginate(30);
```

---

Thanks @Giles Bennett